# Struggling with updating Json.NET

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm sorry for a noob question, but I'm trying to update Json.NET from `v8.0.3` to `v9.0.1` on my Xamarin application to satisfy another package's dependencies. NuGet says that there are some .NETStandard dependencies:

[image]

If I proceed with installation, it adds them as separate packages and some `Consider app.config remapping of assembly` warnings appearing which I have no skill to fix...

Can I update Json.NET to `v9.0.1` without installing `System.*` dependencies as packages (I'm concerned about the size of my app)? If not, what should I do with these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. Seems like this is an known bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22670

> The root cause is in "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets", target
>   _ResolveSatellitePaths.

```
<Target Name="_ResolveSatellitePaths"
    DependsOnTargets="_ResolveAssemblies"
>
  <ResolveAssemblyReference
      AllowedAssemblyExtensions="$(AllowedReferenceAssemblyFileExtensions)"
      AssemblyFiles="@(ResolvedUserAssemblies)"
      FindDependencies="True"
      FindRelatedFiles="False"
      FindSatellites="True"
      SearchPaths="$(AssemblySearchPaths)"
      TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)"
      TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName="$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)"
      TargetFrameworkDirectories="$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)">
    <Output TaskParameter="SatelliteFiles" ItemName="_AndroidResolvedSatellitePaths"/>
  </ResolveAssemblyReference>
```

> The invocation to ResolveAssemblyReference does not receive an
>   app.config (it should if you have one in the project), or doesn't
>   receive AutoUnify="true" (it should if it gets calculated e.g. from
>   AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences).
>
> If I hack it an add AutoUnify=true to that .targets file, the warnings
>   are gone.
>
> This seems like something that does need fixing, in
>   Xamarin.Android.Common.targets.